# Pass a value from a text box using submit button and post method

Tags: model-view-controller, forms, post, textbox

I'm new to mvc, and I'm having trouble passing the value of a textbox to the controller method.

I've got:

in the aspx page:

> <form action="/Search" method="post" >
>   <input type="submit" value="search"
>   name="id" />

global.asax:

> routes.MapRoute(
>                   "Default",                                              // Route name
>                   "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
>   // URL with parameters
>                   new { controller = "myController", action = "Search", id
>   = "" }  // Parameter defaults

the url I need is

> myController/Search/mySearchTerm

when I type this in manually it works fine.  But when I press the submit button the url I get is:

> myController/Search/Search

If I change the form method to get, I get

> myController/Search/Search?id=search

Answer (score 0):

I missed out the textbox from the code at the top.

What I meant to put in was:

> <form action="/Search" method="post" >
>   <input type="text" /> <input
>   type="submit" value="search" name="id"
>   />

Comment: I've been very stupid. just moved the name="id" from the button to the text box - so <input type="text" name="id" /> <input type="submit" value="search" /> and it works fine.